# Oracle Scheduled Job running Stored Procedure - does not run

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure that runs just fine.  First it creates a databaselink (by calling another stored procedure), then it updates a table, then it closes the link.  As you can see, I had to include the "authid current_user" clause.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPDATE_BATCHES
authid current_user
AS    
BEGIN
  databaselink(1);
  execute immediate ('update MYLOCALTABLE
                      set FLAG= 1
                      where FLAG = 0
                      and id in (select id from REMOTETABLE@LINK)');
  databaselink(0);


END UPDATED_BATCHES;
```

I had been catching exceptions and writing them to a log - but I removed that while trying to debug, hoping to throw an error to the scheduler.  It didn't help.

I have a job running in the scheduler.  I used the wizard in SQL Developer, but here is the SQL it generates.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"<SCHEMA-NAME>".""',
            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            job_action => '<SCHEMA-NAME>.UPDATE_BATCHES',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-03-06 09:37:53.000000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=5;BYMINUTE=0;BYSECOND=0',
            end_date => NULL,
            enabled => TRUE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => 'update the FLAG on the LOCAL table');


    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"<SCHEMA-NAME>".""', 
             attribute => 'restartable', value => TRUE);


    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"<SCHEMA-NAME>".""', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_FULL);
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"<SCHEMA-NAME>".""', 
             attribute => 'raise_events', value => '1');



    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"<SCHEMA-NAME>".""');
END;
```

The scheduled job appears to run just fine.  The run log shows it running every morning - with a status of "succeeded".  I get no error messages.

However, the flag does not update in the table.  If I manually run the stored procedure, it updates as expected.  It's only when running on the scheduler that it does not.

Could this be permissions related?  Any other ideas what to look at?

**EDIT:**
I updated the procedure to save the row count immediately after doing the update.

```
rowsupd := sql%rowcount;
log_errors(p_error_message => 'total olvr batch rows updated: ' || TO_CHAR(rowsupd));
```

I got no result when the schedule job ran.  Not a 0 count - but simply nothing in the table despite the job log showing a successful run.

However, when I manually ran the job, it successfully updated the record.  I'm really baffled.

Comment: Why would you create and remove a database link every day?  Does the link point to a different server every day based on some condition?  Are you sure that the remote table has the data you expect at the time that you query it?  Does `sql%rowcount` indicate that your update statement is updating 1 or more rows?

Comment: it's a security requirement.  We are not allowed to keep the link open for longer than we are using it.  It's the same server.  I am TOLD that the remote table has the data by 2AM and I run the job at 5.  I have not confirmed that by being up at 5AM and querying myself - perhaps I should. I have not tried to run the sql%rowcount.  But I check in the morning and the records aren't updated.  I will add a log that saves sql%rowcount and see the results.

Comment: What does "open" mean to you?  You can close a database link without dropping it.

Comment: sorry - poor choice of words.  No, they want the link actually dropped. Is there a downside to that approach?

Comment: Dropping and recreating objects in general is potentially problematic.  At a minimum, you have to add code to do things like handle the link existing when you try to create it.  If you're using a fixed username, that implies that the password is likely hard-coded in the procedure.  If someone believes that security is enhanced by a database link that can be dropped and recreated at will, that also implies that you're doing something wrong like using a much more powerful user to connect to the remote database than is needed (plus the password is in the create proc).

Comment: ah!  all of that is true.  We do check for if the link exists.  And the user account is a super user.  And connection info is all in the proc.  We'll talk about it internally because that makes a lot of sense.  Thank you!  Also - I have now added the SQL%ROWCount to the proc and will log it as part of the process.

Comment: Don't use a superuser account in a database link.  Particularly not if you just need the ability to read a single table.  Create the database link once, use an account with minimal privileges or use a current_user database link.  Let the database link continue to exist forever.

Comment: ok.  we will def. make that change.  makes perfect sense.